# How to connect to mysql running in container from host machine

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, docker-machine

I'm using https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql to run a mysql container using `docker-machine` in OSX with virtualbox.

I created a new machine

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox mytest
```

The IP is

```
docker-machine ip mytest
192.168.99.103
```

I run the container like this:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql -d \
  -v /opt/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql \
  -e 'DB_USER=sampleuser' -e 'DB_PASS=samplepass' -e 'DB_NAME=sampledb' -e 'DB_REMOTE_ROOT_NAME=root' -e 'DB_REMOTE_ROOT_PASS=samplerootpass' \
  sameersbn/mysql:latest
```

Now, when I try to connect to the mysql in the container from my hostmachine I can connect using user `sampleuser` but not as user `root`.

```
▶ mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.99.103
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.99.1' (using password: YES)
```

`192.168.99.1` is my local laptops ip address

```
▶ ifconfig | grep "192"
    inet 192.168.99.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.99.255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, root only has access from the localhost, 127.0.0.1 & ::1, you need to specifically allow access from 192.168.99.1 or from anywhere using '%' in the user setup : see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html