# Can't connect to mySql docker container with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, docker

I use [Docker Maven Plugin](https://github.com/rhuss/docker-maven-plugin)

When test-integration starts i can connect to mysql on container in terminal with this command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 32795 -uroot -p
```

and everythings works good but when i want to connect mysql in java app with JDBC with this code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:" + System.getProperty("mysqlPort") + "/dashboardmanager",
    "root",
    "root"
);
```

i get this error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:866) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:937) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

I tried:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

and

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

but nothing changed.

[Docker Maven Plugin](https://github.com/rhuss/docker-maven-plugin) Conf:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${docker-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>mysql:5.7.11</name>
                        <run>
                            <env>
                                <MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>root</MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>
                                <MYSQL_DATABASE>dashboardmanager</MYSQL_DATABASE>
                            </env>
                            <ports>
                                <port>mysqlPort:3306</port>
                            </ports>
                        </run>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you running the tests *in* your docker container or do you want to connect *to* the mysql (from outside) container ?

Comment: I want to connect to the mysql from outside

Comment: You have to figure out the IP of your container. Most likely you have to use *docker-machine ip YOUR_ENV* to find out that ip.

Comment: i can connect with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 32795 -uroot -p` in host machine terminal so ip is `127.0.0.1`

Comment: could you make sure that  the value of System.getProperty("mysqlPort") is        32795?

Comment: <port>mysqlPort:3306</port> but this code shows the port is 3306

Comment: This is for binding container 3306 port (mysql default port) to host machine port

Comment: can you use command 'mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 32795 -u root -p root -D dashboardmanager' connect to server?

Comment: Yes, and connects successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was this:

MySql starting process takes about 40 seconds, so i should stay about 40 seconds and after that try to connecting to mySql,  so simple :)

Or i can use these settings in pom.xml:

```
<image>
    <name>mysql:5.7.11</name>
    <alias>mysqlContainer</alias>
    <run>
        <env>
            <MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>root</MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>
            <MYSQL_DATABASE>dashboard</MYSQL_DATABASE>
        </env>
        <ports>
            <port>mysqlPort:3306</port>
        </ports>
        <wait>
            <log>.*port: 3306  MySQL Community Server.*</log>
            <time>120000</time>
        </wait>
    </run>
</image>
```

Comment: Well spotted, and good feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your your MySQL config file (`my.cnf`) set in your mysql container uses:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/6309) (for a reverse case: connecting to mysql running on host from a docker container, but the idea is the same here), in bridge mode, setting `bind-address` to broadcast mode would help validate that mysql is reacheable.

> Note: if you use `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` your MySQL server will listen for connections on all network interfaces. That means your MySQL server could be reached from the Internet ; make sure to setup firewall rules accordingly.

After this test, check "[How to connect to mysql running in container from host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34906355/6309)"

> By default, root only has access from the localhost, 127.0.0.1 & ::1, you need to specifically allow access from 192.168.99.1 or from anywhere using '%' in the user setup.
>   See "[Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html)".

Comment: I use [MYSQL](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mysql/), is this use `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` ?
If problem is ip address why i can connect in host machine terminal with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 32795 -uroot -p` ?

Comment: bind-address is not set.
`my.cnf` is `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

but i don't think problem is this because i can connect in host machine terminal with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 32795 -uroot -p` as said before

Comment: @Arman I though you tested from within the container, not from host (hence my suggestion). Still it is a good test to make: `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`